# ComponentDidUpdate() keeps looping

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

```
class RatingsComponent extends Component{
    componentDidMount(){
        console.log("inside component did MOUNT")
        this.props.fetchReviews()
    }

    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps){
        console.log("inside SHOULD update")
        return (nextProps.reviews !== this.props.reviews);
    }
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
        if(prevProps.reviews !== this.props.reviews)
        {  console.log("inside component did update")
           //    this.props.fetchReviews()  //commented due to infinite looping and hitting API
        }
    }

    render(){
      console.log("inside render");
      return null;
    }
}
```

fetchReviews() is an action that hits the API through saga and updates reviews state through reducer. Code absolutely works fine with componentDidMount(). I was curious and wanted to handle change in data if we are on the same page. I tried adding actionListener but there was no change. I added componentDidUpdate() as above. It worked but API is being hit infinite times. But the value of prevProps.reviews and this.props.reviews are same. I can't understand why this is happening. Any help is appreciated.
P.s: Can't show the code inside render() due to official concerns, simply returning null also causes same issue.

Comment: ّI guess you're having array of objects in reviews ... right?

Comment: Yes @HendEl-Sahli

Comment: You can't dispatch an action that updates the state that you are checking the reference equality of to dispatch the action in the first place. This is why your code is render looping. What is the condition on the page that you want to fetch data again?

Comment: Okay , i get your point. But how come the if condition evaluates to true then.

Comment: You do understand that your reducer returns a new state object and that React uses shallow reference equality to determine when state or props update in order to trigger a rerender, right? If every time your component renders you dispatch an action to update state, you create a cycle.

Comment: Got it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing `fetchReviews` updates **redux store** with new array of objects .... which causes `componentDidUpdate` to fire ... and then `if(prevProps.reviews !== this.props.reviews)` will evaluate to `true` **Even if reviews contains same data** ... but they're pointing to different locations in memory

Comment: `ComponentDidUpdate` is invoked when state or props updates, nothing more. `fetchReviews` is an action, it doesn't return anything.

Comment: If you're updating state with **new array of objects** ... by creating a new location in memory with same data ... It'll cause componentDidUpdate to fire

Comment: @HendEl-Sahli is right. I tried to explain to you in a clearer way what is the issue below

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in the condition: you are not checking if the list of the reviews contains the same IDs, but you are just saying that if `reviews!==previous` fire fetch. This means that every time you retrieve a new array of reviews, even if the content is equal, the fetch request is fired again.

**The loop is:**

UpdateComponent->ComponentUpdated->ConditionIsTrue->FireFetch->UpdateComponent

And condition is always true since you are controlling two arrays in different memory address

Try using a statement like this and see if it solve your issue:

```
//diff is an array that will contain all the differences between this.props and previousProps
let diff= this.props.reviews.filter(review=> !previousProps.reviews.includes(review));

//if there are differences, call fetch
if(diff.lenght>0){
  this.props.fetchReviews()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If we compare two objects with the  == will not give an appropriate result so better to compare with the object values.

For Example:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps){
    console.log("inside SHOULD update")
    return nextProps.reviews.id !== this.props.reviews.id;
}
```

In the above example, I have compared it with the id property you can compare any unique property or main property that is important for re-render